# Connect a function to actionButton in R Shiny Dashboard

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinyjs

I have a Shiny Dashboard with an actionButton in one of my modules

`actionButton("runbutton", "Run Test Now")`

and I have to design it in such a way that when a user clicks on the button, The button will call a function that I have created

```
test_run <- function(){
  library(httr)
  headers = c(
    `Accept` = 'application/vnd.github.v3+json',
    `Authorization` = '{GITHUB_PAT_TOKEN}'
  )
  
  data = '{"ref":"main"}'
  httr::POST(url = 'https://api.github.com/repos/{USER}/{REPO)/actions/workflows/{ID}/dispatches', httr::add_headers(.headers=headers), body = data)
}
```

Is there any way to call test_run() when the user clicks on the button?
I tried to implement using onclick, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The technique I use for `actionButton`s is `observeEvent`. Add something like this to your `server`:

```
observeEvent(input$runbutton,{
   test_run()
})
```

This will call the function you've created when the user clicks the button. There are other ways as well for example using `?observe` or `?req`

Comment: Yes, I also tried using `observeEvent` but the issue with this is when I start the dashboard using the run_dev.R file {golem}, the function gets called automatically, but It does nothing when I click on the button.

Comment: Where are you defining your function in the code? `server`?

Comment: yes !! the`actionButton` is in the `ui` and the `observeEvent` is in the `server`.

Comment: oh i mean where is your `test_run()` function

Comment: At first, it was in the server file, but then I moved it to a separate R file inside the R folder.

Comment: I might know the cause of the error. I guess It's because of the function I created in another file; I tried running again without `observeEvent,` and after running, the function also started automatically i.e. the workflow was initiated without observeEvent` while starting the dashboard.

Comment: We would need more information to help you there, like the content of this other file